# Determining max number v(G) of independent edges in graph G

Tags: math, graph, theory

I have been working on this graph theory problem for a while now with a couple of partners. We have gotten bit stuck and would love a hint to push us in the right direction.

Here is the question:

> The vertex set of the graph G is {1,2...60} and two vertices x,y are joined by an edge if x!=y and x*y is divisible by 6. Determine the maximum number v(G) of independent edges in G.

So we know that 6, 12, 18 ... 60 all connect to every vertice. I am just stumped. Not looking for an answer, just a hint please! 
Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about discrete math, which is more appropriate at math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

One way to think about this is the following: each edge needs to link two numbers such that, across both endpoints, you have a 2 divisor and a 3 divisor.

Of the numbers between 1 and 60, inclusive, there are 20 numbers with no 2 or 3 divisor (namely, 1, 7, 13, 19, ... and 5, 11, 17, ...). There are 10 numbers with both a 2 and a 3 divisor (6, 12, 18, ...). There are 10 numbers with just a 3 divisor (3, 9, 21, ...) and 20 numbers with just a 2 divisor (2, 8, 14, ... and 4, 10, 16, ...).

There is at least one optimal solution that always pairs numbers with 2 and 3 divisors with numbers with neither a 2 divisor nor a 3 divisor. (You can prove this by contradiction). So start with that. That leaves

- 10 numbers with no 2 or 3 divisor
- 10 numbers with just a 3 divisor.
- 20 numbers with just a 2 divisor.

Those 10 numbers with no 2 or 3 divisor have no edges to any of the other numbers, so we can ignore them. Of the remaining numbers, there's edges from all the numbers with 3 divisors to all the numbers with 2 divisors, so you would pair all 10 numbers with a 3 divisor with 10 of the numbers with just a 2 divisor.

Overall, you get 20 edges total: all multiples of 6 with 10 numbers that are either 1 or 5 mod 6, and all numbers that are 3 mod 6 with 10 numbers that are either 2 or 4 mod 6.

Hope this helps!